# PHP explode value does not exist

Tags: php, date, explode

I want to split a date and time string. I have two formats: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM and MM/DD/YYYY

I keep getting errors, when the explode array time values do not exist.
I want it to default to 12:00:00 AM if there are no values.

```
<?php
        $date = array('10/6/2014 10:00:00 AM','10/10/2014');

        foreach ($date as $date) {
        $date = str_replace(array('/', ' ', ':'),',',$date);

        $split_date = explode(",",$date);

                $month = $split_date[0];
                $day = $split_date[1]; 
                $year = $split_date[2];
                $hour = $split_date[3];
                $minute = $split_date[4];
                $second = $split_date[5];
                $AMPM = $split_date[6];

        echo $month;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $day;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $year;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $hour;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $minute;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $second;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $AMPM;
        echo "<br />";echo "<br />";
        }
```

?>

Comment: What is your goal? To split date/ time into the different parts?

Comment: Yes, the date and time needs to be changed to a different format; however, when the time does not exist in the array, it throws errors.

Comment: You don't even have to use a loop! See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code you will not get error

```
$month = isset($split_date[0]) ? $split_date[0] : '';
$day = isset($split_date[1]) ? $split_date[1] : '';
$year = isset($split_date[2]) ? $split_date[2] : '';
$hour = isset($split_date[3]) ? $split_date[3] : '';
$minute = isset($split_date[4]) ? $split_date[4] : '';
$second = isset($split_date[5]) ? $split_date[5] : '';
$AMPM = isset($split_date[6]) ? $split_date[6] : '';
```

Comment: Always Welcome My Friend :)

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you to get the separate values:

```
<?php

    $dates = array('10/6/2014 10:00:00 AM','10/10/2014');
    $split = preg_split('/([\/: X])/', implode(" ", $dates));
    print_r($split);


?>
```

Output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 2014
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 00
    [5] => 00
    [6] => AM
    [7] => 10
    [8] => 10
    [9] => 2014
)
```